# Cloud service not available in the Developer services of android studio 2.2 preview 2 project structure

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

I was trying to add firebase using android studio tools, but what I found no cloud module in the developer services of Android studio project structure.

I can do this using the manual steps but was wondering why I am not seeing it in my Android Studio. Is it due to some missing plugin requirement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Cloud tab (which contains a checkbox to add Firebase to a project) has been removed in Android Studio 2.2.

[image: Cloud tab in Android Studio]

Instead Android Studio 2.2 adds a full Assistant to help you integrate Firebase. You can find this assistant under Tools > Firebase.

To manually add Firebase to your Android Studio project, follow the steps [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/) (or if you're looking to user a 2.x version of the Firebase SDK, look [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html)).