# Not Showing Developer Services in Project Structure

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

Not Showing Developer Services in Project Structure.
Hi currently i am working with 
GoogleFirebase 
and i successfully added  my project with firebase but problem comes when i  need to add the dependency for firebase client but when i open my File->project Structure i am getting this type pf project structure.

[MyProject Strcuture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMVaf.png)

I am not able to add the dependency for firebase client.

This is my 
build.gardle(Project)

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my 
build.gardle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.amk52.mymusic"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation  'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:4.0.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

How should i resolve my problem?

Comment: Can you show the gradle file?

Comment: I have edited in question you can check there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloud service not avalible in the Developer services of android studio 2.2 preview 2 project structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700603/cloud-service-not-avalible-in-the-developer-services-of-android-studio-2-2-previ)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are trying to show the window from `Files > Project Structure` which it doesn't related to current project i suppose.

Instead, if you already added the dependencies of Firebase and Build was successful, go through `Right click` on the project, `Open module Settings` and then you should be able to see the `Developer Services`:

[image]

The developer services has been removed from Android Studio 2.2 and above and this is the link about this;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37704210/4409113

Use `Tools > Firebase`

Comment: Sorry  but still i am  getting the same project structure

Comment: Which version of Android studio are you using?

Comment: I am  using Android 3.1.4 and i am not having option In Tools->FireBase why is this so.?

Comment: Can you please show an image of Tools from Above Toolbar?!

Comment: Hi resolved the problem for Tools->Firebase  and  project structure but how do add the dependency from thier  ? I am having three options in Developer services Adds,Notifiaction,Authentication but no option for cloud

Comment: I have first answered this question but because of confusion, deleted it anyways, it has been removed from AS 2.2 to above and this answers your questions; https://stackoverflow.com/a/37704210/4409113